# Read/Write Removable SD Card (android emulator)

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-sdcard, android-storage

Every time I try to read the informations of SD Card (removable storage), I get android.system.ErrnoException: statvfs failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

I added permissions in manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

As minSdkVersion > 23

```
   public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}
```

The method above is called when the activity is create (it shows the popup and I allow the access)

But when I try to access to the device : (Path = /mnt/media_rw/13F4-1C18)

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(path);
```

I got this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path: /mnt/media_rw/13F4-1C18
                                                          at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:46)
                                                          at android.os.StatFs.<init>(StatFs.java:39)
.....
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: statvfs failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
                                                          at libcore.io.Posix.statvfs(Native Method)
                                                          at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.statvfs(BlockGuardOs.java:304)
                                                          at android.system.Os.statvfs(Os.java:506)
                                                          at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:44)
                                                          at android.os.StatFs.<init>(StatFs.java:39)
```

Have you any idea please how to allow access to REMOVABLE DEVICE ?

Thanks !

Comment: What kind of information do you want to read? And that does not look like a path to the sd card.

Comment: Size of the device (total, available size)

Comment: And what do you want to write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SD Card (external storage)

[Removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) is not [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

> I added permissions in manifest file

Those permissions have nothing to do with removable storage.

> I got this error

You do not have direct filesystem access to arbitrary locations on removable storage.

> Have you any idea please how to allow access to EXTERNAL SD CARD ?

Either:

- On Android 4.4+, use `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, and/or `getExternalMediaDirs()` (note the plural form of the method names) on Android 4.4+, to access directories unique for your app on removable storage. You do not need any permissions to work with these directories.
- On Android 4.4+, stop thinking in terms of removable storage and use [the Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html). This allows the user to specify where the content resides, which could be on external storage, removable storage, Google Drive, etc.
- On Android 7.0+, use `StorageManager` and its `StorageVolume` APIs.