# How to write to external SD card on Android Oreo+?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I would like to know what is the proper way to write to the external SD card on Android Oreo and Pie.

My main aim is to compress files on the SD card. I have seen apps like Moto File explorer and RAR to ask for single permission to write to SD card and nothing else. Moreover, this permission is not the one to write to internal storage. They do not even open the Files UI. See the image below (I do not have reputation to post images):

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SayantanRC/app-images/master/external%20write%20permission.png

Versus the ordinary permission to write to internal storage

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SayantanRC/app-images/master/internal%20write%20permission.png

I just do not know what is this permission and where to start.

Please note that I am not talking about `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. I have access to it (I have also asked for the permission during runtime.) My problem is, say the path to SD card is `/storage/B840-4A40` and if I try

```
File f = new File("/storage/B840-4A40");
Toast.makeText(this, "writable: " + f.canWrite(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This returns `false`.
It would be great if anyone can point me in the right direction. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That path isn't the same across devices. It depends on your SD card.

Comment: I know. I just assumed it. It's path to external SD card.

Comment: See also: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23430154/115145, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45283211/115145, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am not sure if the question is a duplicate to the one you marked. As per the answer in the referred question, the method getStorageDirectories() does not return the external SD card path. Also the application from which I have taken the screenshot does not even open the Files app like ES Explorer does.

Comment: I do not know what "RAR" is. "Moto File explorer" presumably is a file explorer pre-installed on Moto phones. If so, pre-installed apps can be pre-granted rights that ordinary apps cannot hold, and device manufacturers can create their own custom "permission-ish" mechanisms for pre-installed apps to use. Ordinary apps will be limited to `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, `getExternalMediaDirs()`, `StorageVolume`, the Storage Access Framework, etc.

Comment: "Moto File explorer" works on any other device, so its not device specific functionality. You can check RAR here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rarlab.rar
These are not the only ones. There are other popular applications like Solid Explorer and Amaze explorer.